# Which Unity types are nullable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullable

Why is it that putting

```
Renderer? myRenderer;
```

generates the error

```
The type 'Renderer' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'
```

whereas

```
Vector3? myVector3;
```

does not?

By way of example, I want to be able to write

```
void ApplyMaterial(Material material)
{
    Renderer? renderer = targetDefinedExternally;
    renderer?.material = material;
}
```

In comparison, the following produces no errors

```
Vector3? vector;
float? magnitude = vector3?.magnitude;
vector3?.Normalize();
```

This suggests some Unity types are nullable whereas others aren't. How can I tell which is which? (And is there an elegant way to work around this?)

Comment: You should not use `renderer?.material = ...`, since the null coalescing operator is not reliable in Unity, because Unity has it's own implementation of a null object for debugging purposes resulting in invalid (`null`) objects not being c#'s `null` resulting in an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. That answers my comment to the answer by Sweeper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**All types can be nullable.**

A type is either a reference type or a value type. Reference types are nullable on their own. Value types are not nullable by default, and can be made nullable using the `?` prefix.

[`Renderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html) is a class, which means it's a reference type. So you don't need the `?` and it will work:

```
void ApplyMaterial(Material material)
{
    Renderer renderer = targetDefinedExternally;
}
```

[`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is a struct, which is a value type. This is why you can do:

```
Vector3? myVector3;
```

If your [version of Unity](https://unity3d.com/beta/2020.2b) supports C# 8, `Renderer?` would have worked too, since that is using the [nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) feature from C# 8.

---

That said, `renderer?.material = material;` won't work in either case, because the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.` can't be used in the LHS of an assignment :(

Comment: Thanks for explaining struct vs class in relation to value type vs reference type. Super useful. I tried the code you suggested but `renderer?.material = material;` results in the error `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer` whereas `if (renderer != null) renderer.material = material;` does not.

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone Actually this is not just due to Unity. You just can't use `?.` in the left hand side of an assignment. `?.` is only for _member access_. Thomas' point about not using it in Unity still stands though.